# Landscape layout does not appear when the phone is rotated

Tags: android

I am trying to create a landscape layout for my android app. So I created a separate folder called **layout-land** and inside that I created the `main.xml` for landscape mode.

But when I rotate the phone it does not appear the landscape layout, instead it shows me a message like this,

```
Unfortunately Nasa Daily Image app has stopped
```

When I put `configChanges="orientation|screensize"` property inside activity tag, then it shows the portrait layout, even I rotated the phone. (This is clear to me because the activity does not restart at the runtime).

Next I tried `configChanges="orientation"` and **override the onConfigurationChanged** method as follows,

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if(newConfig.orientation== Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }else if(newConfig.orientation== Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

But still I am getting the error message.

So I want to display the landscape layout. How to fix this?

Logcat

```
12-31 12:04:02.367  16728-16728/com.nasa.nasadailyimageapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL      EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.nasa.nasadailyimageapp.MainActivity.resetDisplay(MainActivity.java:104)
        at com.nasa.nasadailyimageapp.MainActivity.access$100(MainActivity.java:22)
        at com.nasa.nasadailyimageapp.MainActivity$2.run(MainActivity.java:150)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: "Unfortunately Nasa Daily Image app has stopped" : Please post the logcat for this

Comment: @AstralProjection Can you explain more?

Comment: You are getting a NullPointer exception in your resetDisplay() function, that means somehow you are losing on some values which are necessary for the display or whatever calculation. To persist your variables even if an activity restart is forced by orientation change you store them somewhere and that somewhere is called as a "Bundle". http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Saving_and_Restoring_the_User_Interface_State_of_an_Android_Activity

Answer (score 3):

Android automatically pulls the appropriate resource from the appropriate folder on configuration changes UNLESS you declare that you are handling those changes, which you have done. Remove the configChanges="orientation" from the manifest and the onConfigurationChanged() routine and it will work.

In other words, by declaring configChanges="orientation", you are saying "No, Android! I'll deal with loading the orientation change myself." Not what you want, I presume.

One additional thing to be aware of, is that when you let Android deal with the orientation (or any configuration change), it will destroy your current Activity and recreate it using the  new resources for the new configuration. So be sure to account for this (save/restore state needed).

Comment: Problem is when I executed the app first time, then it loads the data to the portrait layout and it is working fine. I created the landscape  layout using the same views(I changed only the position of two buttons). When I rotate the phone it should restart the activity and loads the landscape layout with the same data. right? (since it is going to execute the onCreate() again). I can't understand why I am getting an error? (If it is working for portrait , then it have to work on landscape as well)

Comment: My app is getting the RSS feeds from the Nasa web site, So I think without saving the status in a bundle, I let the program to get the data again when it loads the landscape layout.

Answer (score 0):

In the landscape layout I didn't put the relevant IDs as in the portrait layout. That is why null exception came during the execution. It is necessary to have the same resource ids in both layouts.